# Selenium on NET Core works differently on Linux

Tags: c#, selenium, dictionary

I developed a little scraper using net core and selenium, but I noticed that my program works properly on windows and it doesn't work on centos. It seems like the driver object on centos has a structure totally different from windows.

This is my test code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = SetupTest2();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            Console.WriteLine(driver.PageSource);
        }

        public static IWebDriver SetupTest2()
        {
            String driverPath = @"/root";
            String driverExecutableFileName = "chromedriver";
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--headless");
            options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath, driverExecutableFileName);
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            return driver;
        }        
    }
```

On windows it works properly. The Console.WriteLine prints the source of the page.
Instead on centos it prints that

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

Is there something I can do to fix this issue? Or I have to switch to something different as python?